# jquery how to add and remove alert number in page title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a real time script, that will run ajax to check new messages.
I have a page title that I'd like to get:

```
$(document).find("title").text();
```

for example: page1, page2...

But I'd like to add a number in front of it, the number of new messages ajax will return.

```
eg: (2) page1.
```

has two new messages.
I think it is simple. Just get title, concat with the number ajax returned and add to title.

```
document.title = concat_var;
```

the real problem here is how to remove this (2), add (3) if new messages arrive or remove it from title if user click on message icon.

can I add a class? like:

```
<title><span class=numbermessages>(2)</span> page1</title>
```

Or another suggestion?

Comment: If you know that `document.title` may or may not contain brackets and number inside them in the beginning, why not use a regular expression to remove it to get a "normalized" value which you can later alter again as you like?

Comment: @ri-chan thanks for your idea, I'll try some regular expression to get the (number)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.title='('+concat_var+document.title.substr(document.title.indexOf(')'));
```

EDIT: To remove, use this:

```
document.title=document.title.substr(document.title.indexOf(') ')+1);
```

[Demo](https://ayunami2000.github.io/?html=PHRpdGxlPikgWW91ciBzaXRlPC90aXRsZT4KPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0idmlld3BvcnQiIGNvbnRlbnQ9IndpZHRoPWRldmljZS13aWR0aCxpbml0aWFsLXNjYWxlPTEuMCI+CjxidXR0b24gb25jbGljaz0iY2xlYXJJbnRlcnZhbCh3aW5kb3cudGl0bGVTZXR0ZXIpO2RvY3VtZW50LnRpdGxlPWRvY3VtZW50LnRpdGxlLnN1YnN0cihkb2N1bWVudC50aXRsZS5pbmRleE9mKCcpICcpKzEpOyI+UmVtb3ZlPC9idXR0b24+&css=&js=d2luZG93Lm9ubG9hZD1mdW5jdGlvbigpewp3aW5kb3cudGl0bGVTZXR0ZXI9d2luZG93LnNldEludGVydmFsKGZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7CnZhciBjb25jYXRfdmFyPU1hdGguZmxvb3IoTWF0aC5yYW5kb20oKSoxNDkpKzE7CndpbmRvdy5zZXRUaW1lb3V0KGZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7CmRvY3VtZW50LnRpdGxlPScoJytjb25jYXRfdmFyK2RvY3VtZW50LnRpdGxlLnN1YnN0cihkb2N1bWVudC50aXRsZS5pbmRleE9mKCcpJykpOwp9LE1hdGguZmxvb3IoTWF0aC5yYW5kb20oKSoyMDApKzUwKTsKfSwyNTApOwp9Ow==&tab=3&fullscreen)

Comment: thanks! this: `document.title='('+concat_var+')' + document.title;` will add. but how to remove it later? the (2) number?

Comment: Edited to answer your question

Comment: Now it's fixed (and this time tested too)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the regular expression.

```
document.title = document.title.replace(/\(\d+\)\s+/, "");
```

Specific to your question. Assuming `concat_var` returns the numbers.

```
document.title = "(" + concat_var + ") " + document.title.replace(/\(\d+\)\s+/, "");
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote it up if it helped?